# Columns re-sized after column-level-encryption is performed (Always encrypted)

Tags: sql, azure, encryption, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I am trying to do column level encryption in sql-azure database. When encryption completes successfully, I observed that column size is getting modified; actually reduced, surprisingly in other table columns which are not encrypted at all.

example: Perform encryption on "table:A", but in "table:B" column sizes are reduced automatically from nvarchar(500) to nvarchar(100).

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying the datatype of a column (that you are not encrypting) gets changed from nvarchar(500) to nvarchar(100)? This is definitely not an expected behavior. Please share the schema before and after encryption, and how you are encrypting your columns.

What is expected is a change of the size needed to store values in a column that gets encrypted. For example, if the SSN column columns stores 11-character strings (CHAR(11)), the below query will return 11 before the column is encrypted, and it will return 65 after the column gets encrypted.

SELECT DATALENGTH(SSN) from [Patients]

You can find more details on how the size of a column changes after the column is encrypted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-cryptography#ciphertext-length.

Thanks,

Jakub